# Ksoap2 for Android

Tags: android, eclipse, ksoap2

I'm using Ksoap2 on Android for connecting Webservice. When I add file Ksoap2.jar downloaded from this [site:](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/source/browse/m2-repo/com/google/code/ksoap2-android/#ksoap2-android/ksoap2-base%253Fstate%253Dclosed)

All of versions that i get cannot use. The detail of error is: **"Archive for required library: `'C:/Users/xxx/workspace/ksoap2-android-2.6.1.jar'` in project 'yyy' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file"**

help me, plz!

Comment: Use this -> http://ksoap2-android.googlecode.com/svn/m2-repo/com/google/code/ksoap2-android/ksoap2-android-assembly/2.6.0/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar and make sure that download completed successfully.

Comment: Thanks, but it hasn't AndroidHttpTransport. I had to use HttpTransportSE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this  http://forums.spout.org/threads/eclipse-error-cannot-be-read-or-is-not-a-valid-zip-file.1233/

I think your zip file may be corrupted or did not  get downloaded complete....